# Most jQuery-like HTML parser for Ruby

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, parsing

What HTML parser for Ruby will I find easiest to use if I'm already familiar / in love with jQuery?

Such a parser would have jQuery's overall philosophy -- "grab some HTML elements (using CSS selectors) and do things with them" -- and in addition have equivalents for all of jQuery's DOM manipulation functionality (`prepend()`, `after()`, etc).

Obviously it wouldn't make sense for a server-side parser to support jQuery event, effect, or AJAX functionality.

**Edit:** Hpricot does this pretty well (e.g., `doc.search('#menu').inner_html`) -- is there anything with a better API? (When I Google "nokogiri v. hpricot" all I get are speed comparisons. I don't care about speed! I just want a library that's fun / easy to use!)

Comment: Nokogiri's API is pretty similar to Hpricot's (not to mention that Nokogiri can emulate Hpricot's API).  I'm not particularly clear on what you think is wrong with Hpricot's API.  What are you looking for that it doesn't give you?

Comment: > What are you looking for that it doesn't give you?

Nothing in particular, I was just wondering if another library was generally preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd probably be most at home with [Hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot).  Heck, it even says it right there on the front page:

> Hpricot is a very flexible HTML
>   parser, based on Tanaka Akira’s HTree
>   and John Resig’s jQuery, but with the
>   scanner recoded in C. I’ve borrowed
>   (what I believe to be) the best ideas
>   from these wares to make Hpricot heaps
>   of fun to use.

Answer (score -5):

Wouldn't this be more than achievable using nothing other than Ruby's own [string manipulation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Replacement,_Substitution_and_Insertion) and some *very* light regex (maybe? I haven't touched ruby in a while).

Comment: Nothing but the most basic manipulation of HTML should *ever* be done using string manipulation and regex.