# There’s PyQuery… is there one for Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

You guys know [PyQuery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)?

I was wondering if there’s an equivalent for Ruby.

Comment: actually, no, I didn't know PyQuery. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: fasdfasdf, you might want to accept an answer to one of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hpricot - [Most jQuery-like HTML parser for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223793/most-jquery-like-html-parser-for-ruby)

Comment: [Hpricot is now deprecated](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot#hpricot-is-over). Its README suggests using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) instead. Nokogiri, too, allows selecting elements using a jQuery-like syntax (using [the `Node#css` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css)).

Answer (score 1):

There's JRails, but it's outdated. If you're just looking for a way to use JQuery with Rails though: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery